# Shenandoah Garbage Collector - how redirection pointer works in region that was collected twice before app change object state?

Tags: java, garbage-collection

Accroding to [article](https://blogs.oracle.com/javamagazine/understanding-garbage-collectors) `Shenandoah GC` works with adding new pointer that
tell where the object was moved.

Let's say:

```
region_A  redirection_pointer 
ObjectA   12345
```

then `GC` is moving this object somewhere:

```
region_A  redirection_pointer 
(no object)   12345
```

then after some time `GC` is adding new object to this region:

```
region_A  redirection_pointer 
ObjectB   11111
```

and just now app want to do something with `ObjectA`, but it 
does not have proper object and redirection pointer.

How this works?

Comment: I think this was covered multiple times in Shenandoah talks. See the "Concurrent Copy" section here: https://shipilev.net/talks/javazone-Sep2018-shenandoah.pdf. That for the "old" Shenandoah (colloquially known as 1.0). For newer Shenandoah, see here: https://shipilev.net/talks/jugbb-Sep2019-shenandoah.pdf. 

From the way you asked the question, I guess the major misunderstanding is the idea that region from where the object was copied is recycled after the move. It is actually recycled *after all the references were updated*, which means every heap reference knows where `ObjectA` now is.

Answer (score 1):

I think this was covered multiple times in Shenandoah talks. See the "Concurrent Copy" section [here](https://shipilev.net/talks/javazone-Sep2018-shenandoah.pdf). That for the "old" Shenandoah (colloquially known as 1.0). For newer Shenandoah, see [here](https://shipilev.net/talks/jugbb-Sep2019-shenandoah.pdf).

From the way you asked the question, I guess the major misunderstanding is the idea that region from where the object was copied is recycled right after the move. It is actually recycled after all the references were updated, which means every heap reference knows where ObjectA now is. Therefore, you never run in the situation when there is something that needs the forwarding pointer from the old region.